# Display inline-block, it's working in HTML but not in PHP (I'm getting values in DB)

Tags: php, html, css

I find it's very strange. Even though it's working in HTML but not in PHP.

I will tell you the difference.

Here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/goz8463a/) for HTML.

And for PHP. The following code are below:

```
<div class="home-section">
    <h1> BEST SELLER </h1>
    <p>
         <form method="POST" action="cart_update.php">
         <ul class=\"home-section-img\">
        <?php
            include("config.php");  

            $current_url = base64_encode($url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
            $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id ASC");
            if ($results) {

                while($obj = $results->fetch_object())
                {

                            echo "<li>";
                            echo '  <a href="#">
                                    <img src="images/'.$obj->product_img_name.'">
                                    <p> '.$obj->price.' </p>
                                    <p> '.$obj->product_name.' </p>
                                    </a>';
                            echo "</li>";  
                }
            }
        ?>
        </ul>
        </form>
    </p>
</div>
```

I tried to convert from HTML to PHP. The result is `display:inline-block;` doesn't work in PHP. but HTML works well for `display:inline-block;`. The images in php should float left even though I am not using `float:left;`, i just want to use `display:inline-block;` So that I can insert pictures in database as many as I want. The images must be placed in the centered div. Any ideas?

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get any output at all since there's a `>` missing in the line `echo '<form method="POST" action="cart_update.php"';`?

Comment: You forgot > here 
echo '<form method="POST" action="cart_update.php">';

And your <form> must be outside the while

Comment: Also try to be stricter with your coding style, `echo '  <a href=\"#\">` should be just `echo '  <a href="#">`. You are mixing single and double quotes wildly.

Comment: @Paul Sorry, missing quotes badly. I have corrected it. Thanks for let me know. Anyway, it doesn't work because the image should be float left. It works well in JSFiddle above but not works in PHP. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following line should be outside of `while` loop and write `<form>` properly .

```
 echo '<form method="POST" action="cart_update.php">';
 echo "<ul class=\"home-section-img\">";
```

and

```
echo "</ul>";
echo "</form>";
```

Comment: No, it's still not okay because I want the images in PHP look centered in div without using `float:left;`. It works in HTML (JSFiddle above).

Comment: Oh it worksssssss! Because of `<form>` inside echo. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Do you even apply CSS to your PHP page? CSS has nothing to do with PHP, it's just some design rules that apply to your HTML output regardless of the source (whether written "by hand" in jsFiddle or coming from a PHP script).

Comment: Good solution +1